# uipickerView is displayed after click on textfield then uiview then agin the same textfielf

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with Xcode and Swift.
In scenario, I have three uitextfields and one uipickerview, the data of uipickerviews change for each textfield, and that work fine, but the problem is that for display the first uipickerview I must click on the first uitextfield then on UIView then again on uitextfield for display a uipickerview, then for display the picker for second uitextfield, I had to click on the second uitextfield then on UIView then again on the second uitextfield for display uipickerview, and the same for the third uitextfield (uitextfield then UIView then uitextfield) for display the uipickerview, each uitextfield have its datasource of uipickerview different from the other.

This is the short code:

```
 var level =  [String]()
let pickerSchool = UIPickerView()
var lastPressedTextField: UITextField?
var currentIndex = 0
let toolBar = UIToolbar()

@IBOutlet weak var cityTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var levelSchoolTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var schoolTextField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
toolBar.sizeToFit()
        let buttonDone = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closePicker))
        toolBar.setItems([buttonDone], animated: true)
}


@IBAction func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        lastPressedTextField = textField
        lastPressedTextField?.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        lastPressedTextField!.inputView = pickerSchool
    }


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
     func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    
    if lastPressedTextField == cityTextField {
        return RequestService.gettenCity[row]
    } else if lastPressedTextField == levelSchoolTextField {
        return  level[row]
    } else if lastPressedTextField == schoolTextField {
        return  RequestService.gettenSchool[row]
    }
    return ""
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if lastPressedTextField == cityTextField {
            return RequestService.gettenCity.count
        } else if lastPressedTextField == levelSchoolTextField {
            return   level.count
        } else if lastPressedTextField == schoolTextField {
            return  RequestService.gettenSchool.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        currentIndex = row
        if lastPressedTextField == cityTextField {
            self.cityTextField.text = RequestService.gettenCity[row]
        }
        else if lastPressedTextField == levelSchoolTextField {
            self.levelSchoolTextField?.text = level[row]
        }
        else  {
            self.schoolTextField.text = RequestService.gettenSchool[row]
        }
    }

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        pickerSchool.isHidden = false
        textField.inputView = pickerSchool;
        return false
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        pickerSchool.isHidden = true
    }

@objc func closePicker(){
        if lastPressedTextField == cityTextField {
            lastPressedTextField?.text = RequestService.gettenCity[currentIndex]
        } else if lastPressedTextField == levelSchoolTextField {
            //  lastPressedTextField?.text = level[currentIndex]
            //
            let newParameters : Parameters = [
                "city": cityTextField.text!,
                "level" : levelSchoolTextField.text!
            ]
            api =  URL(string: "http://localhost/mesamies/getschools.php")
            repository.schoolSelect(url: api!, method: .post, parameters: newParameters) { dataResponse in
                switch dataResponse {
                case .success(let schools):
                    let school = schools.count
                    for i in 0...school-1{
                        RequestService.gettenSchool.append(schools[i].name!)
                        RequestService.gettenSchoolId.append(Int(schools[i].id!)!)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            } //
        }
        else if lastPressedTextField == schoolTextField {
            schoolTextField?.text = RequestService.gettenSchool[currentIndex]
        }
        lastPressedTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

If you want see all the code, this is the link on GitHub:

https://github.com/mdolwan/Projet_12/blob/master/MesAmies/Controllers/SettingViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

In your `SettingViewController` class, you have this function:

```
@IBAction func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    lastPressedTextField = textField
    lastPressedTextField?.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    lastPressedTextField!.inputView = pickerSchool
}
```

connected to each text field's `Editing Did End` event.

You almost certainly want it to be called on `Editing Did Begin`.